# ggplot: remove lines at ribbon edges

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `ggplot` to plot time course data (fixation proportions over time to different objects on the screen) and want to use a ribbon to show the SE, but the ribbon itself has lines at the top and bottom edges, which makes reading the graph a bit harder. I haven't been able to figure out how to get rid of those edge lines. Here is my plot code:

```
ggplot(d, aes(Time, y, color = Object, fill = Object)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line", size = 2) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", geom = "ribbon", alpha = .3)
```

Any suggestions?

Here is a minimal working example. I've compressed my data to:

```
   Time Object          y      lower     upper
 1 1000      C 0.12453389 0.04510504 0.2039627
 2 1000      T 0.58826856 0.37615078 0.8003864
 3 1000      U 0.09437160 0.03278069 0.1559625
 4 1100      C 0.12140127 0.03943988 0.2033627
 5 1100      T 0.64560823 0.44898727 0.8422292
 6 1100      U 0.06725172 0.01584248 0.1186610

d <- structure(list(Time = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1100L, 1100L, 1100L), Object = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("C", 
"T", "U"), class = "factor"), y = c(0.12453389, 0.58826856, 0.0943716, 
0.12140127, 0.64560823, 0.06725172), lower = c(0.04510504, 0.37615078, 
0.03278069, 0.03943988, 0.44898727, 0.01584248), upper = c(0.2039627, 
0.8003864, 0.1559625, 0.2033627, 0.8422292, 0.118661)), .Names = c("Time", 
"Object", "y", "lower", "upper"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

and here is the new plot code:

```
ggplot(d, aes(Time, y, color = Object, fill = Object)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = .3)
```

[image]

Comment: Would you construct a minimal working example. That means you should add in some simple data to run your graph command.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have helped.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can remove the border using the `colour` argument:

```
ggplot(d, aes(Time, y, color = Object, fill = Object)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = .3, colour = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work when you've already assigned `colour` to a sorting variable. Instead, the `linetype=0` approach mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755041/ggplot-remove-lines-at-ribbon-edges?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#comment81568313_17180432) below user443854's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17180432/4581200) worked perfectly!

Answer (score 41):

`geom_ribbon` understands `linetype` aesthetic. If you want to map linetype to a variable include it in the `aes()` argument, otherwise, place `linetype` outside and just give it `0`, like so:

```
ggplot(d, aes(Time, y, color = Object, fill = Object)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), linetype = 0, alpha = .3)
```

[image]

More info here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_ribbon.html

Comment: `linetype=NA` does not work for me, however, `linetype=0` or `linetype='blank'` works.
http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_linetype_size_shape.html

Comment: I'm using ggplot2_2.2.1 -- I can confirm `linetype=NA` no longer works (gives error `invalid line type`). `linetype=0` or `linetype='blank'` both currently work.

Answer (score 9):

`ggplot2`'s `geom_ribbon()` now includes an `outline.type` argument that helps control how the ribbon outlines are displayed.

### Outline Type

```r
library(tidyverse)

huron <- tibble(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron))

huron %>%
    ggplot(aes(year, level)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level - 1, ymax = level + 1), 
                fill = "grey70", color = "red", 
                outline.type = "lower") +
    geom_line(aes(y = level))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Linetype = 0

Alternatively, as suggested we can set `linetype = 0` to remove all lines.

```r
library(tidyverse)

huron <- tibble(year = 1875:1972, level = as.vector(LakeHuron))

huron %>%
    ggplot(aes(year, level)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = level - 1, ymax = level + 1), 
                fill = "grey70", color = "red", linetype = 0) +
    geom_line(aes(y = level))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, instead of `linetype=0` it would be more intuitive if the `outline.type` argument accepted a value such as  `none`  to mean no lines at the ribbon edges.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
ggplot(d, aes(Time, y,  fill=Object)) + 
  geom_line(size=2, aes(colour = Object)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), alpha=.3)
```