# ggplotly with geom_ribbon grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm having some problems in converting a ggplot in to a plotly object, and retaining the same legend attributes. What I want:

- For grouped series, a single line for fit, and faded region for ribbon of same colour, with transparency
- No lines at the edge of the ribbon
- Grouped legends for the lines, points and ribbons

Here is the code showing the 2 approaches I tried based on this answer:
[ggplot: remove lines at ribbon edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755041/ggplot-remove-lines-at-ribbon-edges)

Both have an undesirable effect as you can see when running. Any suggestions would be great :)

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
# fake data
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.frame(x=rep(1:7,2), group=rep(letters[1:2], each=7), value=runif(14))
dt$lwr <- dt$value*.9
dt$upr <- dt$value*1.1

# build plot in ggplot, don't want lines at the edge
pl <- ggplot(data=dt, aes(y=value, x=x, group=group, colour=group,
                          fill=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), alpha=.3, linetype=0) +
  theme_minimal()

# looks ok, no lines at the edges
pl

# lines at edges, single group
ggplotly(pl)

# alternative: try reverting colour to NA
pl2 <- ggplot(data=dt, aes(y=value, x=x, group=group, colour=group,
                          fill=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), alpha=.3, colour=NA) +
  theme_minimal()

# looks ok
pl2

# no lines, but now not grouped, and some weird naming
ggplotly(pl2)
```

Thanks, Jonny

EDIT:
Addition to the accepted answer, in functional form

```
# dd: ggplotly object
library(stringi)
library(rvest)
remove_ggplotly_ribbon_lines <- function(dd){
  find <- rvest::pluck(dd$x$data, "fillcolor")
  w <- which(!sapply(find, is.null))
  for(i in w){
    dd$x$data[[i]]$line$color <- 
      stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(dd$x$data[[i]]$line$color, ",[\\d.]*\\)$", ",0.0)")
  }
  return(dd)
}
remove_ggplotly_ribbon_lines(ggplotly(pl))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi this is more a comment than an answer but I do not have right to post comments.

If you investigate the ggplotly object you will see that it is actually just a list. Changing the right elements of the list helps in controlling plot options.

The solution below just changes the alpha of the lines at ribbon edges. Hope this helps

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)
dt <- data.frame(x=rep(1:7,2), group=rep(letters[1:2], each=7), value=runif(14))
dt$lwr <- dt$value*.9
dt$upr <- dt$value*1.1

# build plot in ggplot, don't want lines at the edge
pl <- ggplot(data=dt, aes(y=value, x=x, group=group, colour=group,
                      fill=group)) +
geom_point() +
geom_line() +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), alpha=.3, linetype=0) +
theme_minimal()

# looks ok, no lines at the edges
pl

# no lines at edges
dd = ggplotly(pl)
dd$x$data[[3]]$line$color = "rgba(248,118,109,0.0)"
dd$x$data[[4]]$line$color = "rgba(0,191,196,0.0)"
dd
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think I can find a way to make the 3, 4 numbers adaptive by plucking out some elements of the list

Comment: editing the original question to add your answer in functional form fyi